# Are these fast convergent series for the lemniscate constant and $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$ already known?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

[**Updated on Nov.10, Dec.05.2023 and Feb.18.2024**] Applying a similar approach followed in these MO questions, for [Catalan's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424055/catalans-constant-fast-convergent-series) and [Apery's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454929/ap%C3%A9rys-constant-zeta3-fastest-convergent-series) Constants, i.e. Wilf-Zeilberger proofs starting from Dougall's sum, working together with nonlinear $_2F_1$ and $_3F_2$ hypergeometric transformations, I have found four convergent series for the Lemniscate Constant $s = 2\varpi$ and two for $s=\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$. As far as I know, they are currently the fastest series to compute such constants with arbitrary precision (they belong to a highly efficient computing class -P2B3 class- specially fitted to apply the binary splitting algorithm).

More details can be found in these links [(1)](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/news/2023.html#2023_10_25), [(2)](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/) and [(3)](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/internals/formulas.html)

I am not sure if some of them has been already published, so the question is very simple.
Is any of these series known?

**NOTE** As of **Feb.18.2024** question remains open for Eqs.(1), (2), (3), (7) and (11) below.

We use the following notation, where the constant $s$ is expressed as $$s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\rho^n\cdot\frac{p(n)}{r(n)}\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 a & b & c & ... & z \\
 A & B & C & ... & Z \\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p(n)}{r(n)}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{r(k)}{q(k)}$$ here $p(n),q(n),r(n)$ are polynomials non vanishing for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $q(n)$ and $r(n)$ have the same degree $d$ and the convergence ratio $|\rho|$ is the absolute value of the ratio of the leading terms of $r(n)$ and $q(n)$. The ratio of products of Pochhammer's symbols (rising factorials) is written as
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
 a & b & c & ... & z \\
 A & B & C & ... & Z \\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n=\frac{(a)_n(b)_n(c)_n ... (z)_n}{(A)_n(B)_n(C)_n ... (Z)_n} $$ where the degree $d$ is the number of elements in a row (they are the same for both rows) and $$(w)_n = \frac{\Gamma(w+n)}{\Gamma(w)}=w(w+1)(w+2)...(w+n-1)$$

The computational speed is measured through the [binary splitting cost](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/internals/binary-splitting.html) $$ C_s = - \frac{4d}{\log|\rho|}.$$ This allows to (asymptotically) rank, classify and compare different hypergeometric-type algorithms by performance.  Series are:

---

**A.** For the **lemniscate constant**

$$2\varpi =\frac{\;\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=5.2441151085842396209296791797822388273655...$$a trascendental number, See *Finch, Steven R.*, [**Mathematical constants**](https://oeis.org/A247988), Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications 94. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-81805-2/hbk). xx, 602 p. (2003). [ZBL1054.00001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1054.00001). (Section 6.1)

**I)** The first one has a cost $C_s=-4\cdot8/\log\frac{1}{2^{24}}=1.9326.$. It is $$\begin{equation*}2\varpi=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2^{24}}\right)^n\cdot\frac{P(n)}{R(n)}\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{8}&\frac{3}{8}&\frac{5}{8}&\frac{7}{8}&\frac{3}{16}&\frac{7}{16}&\frac{11}{16}&\frac{15}{16}\\
\frac{1}{32}&\frac{5}{32}&\frac{9}{32}&\frac{13}{32}&\frac{17}{32}&\frac{21}{32}&\frac{25}{32}&\frac{29}{32}\\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}$$ where $$ P(n)  =  750599893155840\,n^7 - 2465512126676992\,n^6 + 3305810396971008\,n^5 - 2327426831319040\,n^4 + 919690491432960\,n^3 - 201024828994048\,n^2 
 + 22012514018112\,n - 897181286400$$$$R(n)=(8n-1)(8n-3)(8n-5)(8n-7)(16n-1)(16n-5)(16n-9)(16n-13)$$

**II)** The second series gives the reciprocal of this constant with about $3.01$ decimal digits per term. It has a cost $C_s=1.5661$: $$\begin{equation*}\frac{1}{2\varpi}=C_0\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{2^9}{3^9\cdot7^6}\right)^n\cdot\frac{n^2\,P(n)}{R(n)}\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{36}&\frac{7}{36}&\frac{13}{36}&\frac{19}{36}&\frac{25}{36}&\frac{31}{36}\\
1&1&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}$$ where $C_0=2\cdot3^{9/2}\cdot7^{5/6}$ and $$P(n) = 99446494228488\,n^5 - 296948949253092\,n^4 + 339735211540956\,n^3 - 185806427026662\,n^2 + 48479683290426n - 4840729282291$$ $$R(n)=-(36n-5)(36n-11)(36n-17)(36n-23)(36n-29)(36n-35)$$

**III)** The third one for this constant, performs pretty fast. It has a cost $C_s=1.5643$:
$$\begin{equation*}\frac{1}{2\varpi}=C_1\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2^9}{11^9}\right)^n\,\frac{n^2\,P(n)}{R(n)}\,\left[\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{36}&\frac{5}{36}&\frac{13}{36}&\frac{17}{36}&\frac{25}{36}&\frac{29}{36}\\
1&1&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}$$ where $C_1 = 2\cdot3^{15/4}\cdot11^{7/4}$ and $$P(n) = 17680561647336\,n^5 - 52825631815620\,n^4 + 60473303319276\,n^3 - 33092086224942\,n^2 + 8638260598818\,n - 862864755643$$ $$R(n)=(36n-7)(36n-11)(36n-19)(36n-23)(36n-31)(36n-35)$$

**IIIa) [Updated Nov.10.2023]**  The following fast series to compute the lemniscate constant

$$\begin{equation*}2\varpi=5C_2 \cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{7^4\cdot23^4}\right)^n\cdot\frac{n^2\,P(n)}{R(n)}\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{16}&\frac{5}{16}&\frac{9}{16}&\frac{13}{16}\\
1&1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}$$ where $C_2 = 2^{33/4}\cdot7^{7/4}\cdot23^{7/4}\cdot\pi,\,$ and $$P(n) = 6636032\,n^2 - 6636192\,n + 1659109$$ $$R(n)=(16n-3)(16n-7)(16n-11)(16n-15)$$

has a cost 0.7872 but it needs to compute $\pi$ which has a cost (Chudnovsky) 0.3670. It gives $C_s=1.1542$.

According to Jesús Guillera (pers. comm. Nov. 2023) some of these series can be bisected or trisected. Particularly Eq.(4) can be bisected  into a $\,_2F_1$ function as $$\begin{equation*}2\varpi=C_3\cdot\pi\cdot\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{8},\frac{5}{8};1;\frac{1}{7^2\cdot23^2}\right)\tag{5}\label{5}\end{equation*}$$ for some algebraic value $C_3$. Eq.(5) is a fast monotone series that has a companion $\,_2F_1$ fast alternating series by applying [Euler](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHypergeometricTransformations.html) or [Pfaff](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PfaffTransformation.html) hypergeometric transformation. This gives $$\begin{equation*}2\varpi=C_4\cdot\pi\cdot\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8};1;-\frac{1}{2^6\cdot3^4\cdot5}\right)\tag{6}\label{6}\end{equation*}$$ being $C_4$ an algebraic value. Note that $7^2\cdot23^2=25921$ and $2^6\cdot3^4\cdot5=25920$ and Eqs. (5) and (6) are dual or twin linearly convergent fast series having practically the same performance. These linked $2\varpi\propto\pi\cdot\,_2F_1$ series are proven by purely hypergeometric methods. In fact, you can start from Eq.(2) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758886/method-to-obtain-values-of-gauss-hypergeometric-function), a $\,_3F_2$ series, and use [Clausen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen%27s_formula) to get the (squared) Eq.(6) above. From this, Eq.(5) is obtained applying Euler or Pfaff transformation.

Note also that, if the convergence rate is fixed, Clausen's formula, whenever it can be applied, produces from a fast $\,_3F_2$ series a faster $\,_2F_1$ having a lower computational cost by a factor $\frac{1}{3}$ just by reducing the polynomial degree from $d=3$ to $d=2$.

By Googling "25921 2F1" Eq.(5) is found in Table 4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04742.pdf) where a different proof was obtained by A. Ebisu using special values of Appell's bivariate [F1 function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/) and [Goursat hypergeometric transformation](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.17.0104.01).

Therefore the bisected series **IIIa Eq.(4)** is indeed already known which makes a partial answer to this post.

**IIIb) [New Nov.10.2023. Updated Dec.05.2023]**

Eqs.(5-6) allow to derive the fastest lemniscate constant $2\varpi$ Ramanujan-type series that avoid to compute $\pi$. There are currently two fastest series to compute the lemniscate constant by binary splitting. The proofs of both series are obtained following Guillera's [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.07394.pdf) "A method for proving Ramanujan series for 1/π" using Table 2 for level ℓ = 2, row d = 13 and [also](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.08104.pdf) "WZ proofs of Ramanujan-type series (via 2F1 evaluations)". The first one was obtained by J. Guillera working from Eq.(6) above. It is found and proven in the Appendix of this last publication -Eq.(48)-.

I have found the other one working from Eq.(5). This is

$$\begin{equation*}\frac{1}{2\varpi}=C_5\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{7^2\cdot23^2}\right)^n\cdot(1728\,n+55)\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{8}&\frac{5}{8}\\
1&1\\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n\tag{7}\label{7}
\end{equation*}$$ with $C_5=5^{3/4}\cdot2^{-3/4}\cdot7^{-5/4}\cdot23^{-5/4}$. This series has a cost $C_s=0.7872$.

The proof follows straightforward from Guillera's formula by means of the mentioned Table 2, level ℓ = 2, row d = 13, using Ebisu's formula -Eq.(5) above and [Eq.(A'''.1) in Table 4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04742)- and expanding the rhs after applying $z\frac{d}{dz}$ to both sides of Euler's hypergeometric transformation $\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=(1-z)^{-a}\,_2F_1(a,c-b;c;\frac{z}{z-1})$ with parameters $[a,b,c] = [\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},1]$, $z=-\frac{1}{25920}$ and $\frac{z}{z-1}=\frac{1}{7^2\cdot23^2}$

Lemniscate Eq.(7) above and [Guillera's Eq.(48)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.08104) have been implemented (Dec.02.2023) in y-cruncher's version 0.8.3 Build 9530 as the default algorithms to compute this constant.

---

**B.** For the cube of **$\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$ constant**

**IV) [Updated Feb.18.2024]**

Series is

$$\begin{equation*}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=C_6\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{3^4}{11^4\cdot23^4}\right)^n\cdot\frac{n^2\,P(n)}{R(n)}\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{24}&\frac{7}{24}&\frac{13}{24}&\frac{19}{24}\\
1&1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n\tag{8}\label{8}
\end{equation*}$$ where $C_6 = 2^{7}\cdot6^{1/2}\cdot11^{11/6}\cdot23^{11/6}\cdot\pi^2,\,$ and $$P(n) = 4097152\,n^2 - 4097536\,n + 1024535$$ $$R(n)=(24n-5)(24n-11)(24n-17)(24n-23)$$

This series has cost 0.9020 and $\pi$ (Chudnovsky) provides 0.3670 giving a total cost $C_s=1.2690$.

Following @CarP24's answer -also mentioned by Jesús Guillera (pers. comm. Nov. 2023)- Eq.(8) can be bisected into a $\,_2F_1$ function as $$\begin{equation*}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=C_7\cdot\pi^2\cdot\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{7}{12};1;\frac{3^2}{11^2\cdot23^2}\right)\tag{9}\label{9}\end{equation*}$$ for some algebraic value $C_7$. Eq.(9) is a fast monotone series that has a companion $\,_2F_1$ fast alternating series by applying [Euler](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHypergeometricTransformations.html) or [Pfaff](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PfaffTransformation.html) hypergeometric transformation. This gives $$\begin{equation*}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=C_8\cdot\pi^2\cdot\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{5}{12};1;-\frac{3^2}{2^9\cdot5^3}\right)\tag{10}\label{10}\end{equation*}$$ being $C_8$ an algebraic value. Note that $11^2\cdot23^2=64009$ and $2^9\cdot5^3=64000$ and Eqs. (8) and (9) are dual or twin linearly convergent fast series having practically the same performance. These $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\propto\pi^2\cdot\,_2F_1$ series are proven by purely hypergeometric methods. For instance, from Eq.(42) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.08104.pdf), a $\,_3F_2$ series, use [Clausen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen%27s_formula) to get the (squared) Eq.(10) above. From this, Eq.(9) is obtained applying Euler or Pfaff transformation.

As @CarP24 answered, the bisected series **IV Eq.(8)** is already known [here](https://iamned.com/math) which makes a partial answer to this post.

**IVa) [New Feb.18.2024]**

Eqs.(9-10) allow to derive slightly faster $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3$ Ramanujan-type series that just need to compute $\pi$ instead of $\pi^2$. There are currently two fastest series to compute this constant by binary splitting. The proofs of both series are obtained following Guillera's [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.07394.pdf) "A method for proving Ramanujan series for 1/π" using Table 4 for level ℓ = 1, row d = 7 and [also](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.08104.pdf) "WZ proofs of Ramanujan-type series (via 2F1 evaluations)". The first one was obtained by J. Guillera working from known Eq.(10) above.

I have found the other one working from Eq.(9) now that @CarP24 has placed it in his answer below. This is

$$\begin{equation*}\frac{\pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3}=C_9\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{3^2}{11^2\cdot23^2}\right)^n\cdot(4800\,n+147)\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{12}&\frac{7}{12}\\
1&1\\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n\tag{11}\label{11}
\end{equation*}$$ with $C_9=2^{-1/2}\cdot11^{-7/6}\cdot23^{-7/6}$.

The proof follows from Guillera by means of the mentioned Table 4, level ℓ = 1, row d = 7, using Hakimoglu-Brown formula -Eq.(9) above- and expanding the rhs after applying $z\frac{d}{dz}$ to both sides of Euler's hypergeometric transformation $\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=(1-z)^{-a}\,_2F_1(a,c-b;c;\frac{z}{z-1})$ with parameters $[a,b,c] = [\frac{1}{12},\frac{5}{12},1]$, $z=-\frac{9}{64000}$ and $\frac{z}{z-1}=\frac{3^2}{11^2\cdot23^2}$

A non-native implementation of each series has been done for [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/) software (a high performance platform to compute a huge number of digits of some classical constants, having set several records in this regard). Custom input files were prepared for each formula and series were tested under this special platform against some known formulas and methods that has been used to break the $2\varpi$ and $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$
digits number records. The above formulas outperform providing the fastest binary splitting algorithms to compute these constants.

As it is reported [here](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/#Records) Eq.(4) on Dec.12.2023 and Eq.(8) on Dec.15.2023 were used to beat up to $10^{12}$ the current record of known decimal digits of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ respectively.

**Q:** Excluding series IIIa Eq.(4) and IV Eq.(8), is any of these series known?

Comment: This is crazy, you have my upvote

Comment: Incredible work !

Comment: Seems that this series are faster: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758886/method-to-obtain-values-of-gauss-hypergeometric-function

Comment: Thanks @User. Lets check the binary splitting cost. [ http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/internals/binary-splitting.html ]. For (1) we have Cs = 20/log(8640/3^3/2^2) = 4.564, For (2) we have Cs = 16/log(6635520/4^4) = 1.574. But formula IV) has cost Cs = 0.9020. This one is much faster. II) and III) have costs 1.5661 and 1.5663 respectively. They are very similar to (2) but they do not need to compute Pi which makes  about 10% overload. Anyway I will work on them trying to obtain a faster formula. If I get it I will update this post.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga +1 I took the liberty expressing some huge integers as powers. For example, instead of  $16777216$, it is more informative to express it as $2^{24}$. A lot of your integers turn out to be powers of prime factors.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. For me it's OK.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga By the way, what is the $C_s$ of this formula? $$\frac 1{\sqrt{10}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(6n)!}{(3n)!\,n!^3}\frac {(-1)^n}{(3\cdot160^3)^n} = \frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac 13\right)^6}{12\pi^4}$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII That series has $d=3$ and $\rho=6^6/(3^4\cdot160^3)=9/64000$. It gives $C_s=-4d/\log{\rho}=1.3530$. To compute $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$ you have to add the cost to get $\pi$ that is 0.3670 (Chudnovsky). This gives a total $C_s=1.620$.  This value corresponds to the total series computing cost by binary splitting. Other floating point operations like Nth roots take no significant time.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga Thanks. I’m also trying an experiment on your series similar to what Guillera did for 1/pi. I will post it here if it yields  a nice ressulr.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII You are welcome. From the hypergeometric functions world you get for constant $s=A\cdot\,_pF_{p-1}(z_1)+B\cdot\,_qF_{q-1}(z_2)$ the following cost $$C_s=-4\cdot(\frac{p}{\log|z_1|}+\frac{q}{\log|z_2|})$$. There are some math constants that either have a bad or do not have a P2B3 type formula, $\zeta(5)$ for example which I am currently working on to find one. Catalan Constant $G$ is computed from a formula found by Gosper in the seventies and proved much later by the Pilehrood's. Perhaps transforming $\frac{4G}{\pi}=\,_3F_2(1/2,1/2,1/2;1,3/2;1)$ might provide a faster series.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga Regarding Catalan's constant $G$, how about, $$2G=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{n!}{\;\big(\frac32\big)_n}\right)^3 (-1)^n\, (4n+3)$$
$$2G=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{n!}{\;\big(\frac32\big)_n}\right)^3 \big({-\tfrac18}\big)^n\, (3n+2)$$
How does their speed compare? (These are by Guillera using the WZ method.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. I know them. The first is not linearly convergent but it is Dougall. It can be accelerated using WZ to produce other highly efficient series. If WZ is applied on this, the best it yields is the same Gosper-Pilehrood series that has $C_s=3.07$ It is named Pilehrood-short here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424055/catalans-constant-fast-convergent-series The second one has  $C_s=12/\log8=5.77$ too far from $3.07$. Since $\pi$ is computed ultrafast I guess that $G/\pi$ or $G\cdot\pi$ can produce a faster formula than Gosper-Pilehrood.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII For Catalan constant I think that hypergeometric transformations is the place where to look for. The other place is modular forms where you can find Catalan constant there as the primitive Dirichlet's L(-4,2) but I have already seen it just isolated and not combined with Pi in a way that can produce a fast series.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga Is there any chance that these methods could give faster series for log(2)? (cf (4) in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397770/in-search-of-an-alternative-proof-of-a-series-expansion-for-log-2?rq=1). This would be highly useful.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson. Yes, I think that those T.Amdeberhan formulae for $\log(2)$ can be obtained from Dougall´s sums and proven using WZ pairs. They have a pretty good binary splitting cost $C_s=1.9236$. Perhaps it can be found faster ones, but I am afraid that they can't outperform Machin-like formulae. J. Guillera has linear combinations of 3 ultrafast hypergeometric series to compute $\log(2),\, \log(3)$ and $\log(5)$ at once (it is fast if all three logarithms are required but not isolated values). Preliminary analysis show that they perform faster than computing 3 Machin-like formulae.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga Yes, Machin-like formulas perform quite well. For example the one with x = 251, 449, 4801, 8749 is good and gives log(2), log(3), log(5) and log(7) at the same time. In my experiments the last Amdeberhan formula is slightly better than this formula if one wants only log(2) though. So I'm somewhat optimistic that there might be single series for log(2) that perform even better.

Comment: Ok. @FredrikJohansson. In that case, let me make some experiments for $\log(2)$ and I will give you more details.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson. This series should be better $$\log(2)=\frac{3}{1024}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{P(n)}{R(n)}\cdot\rho^n\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}
 1/2 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 1/6 & 5/6&1 \\
 1/4 & 3/4 & 1/12 & 5/12 & 7/12&11/12 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right]_n$$ where $$P(n)=6291432\,n^5 + 18408276\,n^4 + 20691522\,n^3 + 11114067\,n^2 + 2836265\,n + 273266$$ and $$R(n)=(11 + 12\,n)(5 + 12\,n)(3 + 4\,n)(1 + 4\,n)(7 + 12\,n)(1 + 12\,n)$$ with $\rho=1/262144$. This series comes from a Dougall's sums family. I guess other faster formulae can be found from Ramanujan-like series.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson  The performance of the above series should be compared to the 3-term 26, 4801, 8749 Machin-like formula for the isolated $\log(2)$ value.

Comment: This series is about 5% faster than the Amdeberhan formula. Nice. To be precise, the Machin formula is a bit more efficient on a single core while your series is a bit more efficient using multiple cores, with my particular implementation.What are the Ramanujan-like series? One wishes log(2) had something comparable to the Chudnovsky series since it is a just as fundamental a constant as pi!

Comment: @FredrikJohansson. Nice to hear that. Ramanujan-like series is a family of formulae that have the fastest hypergeometric type series to apply the binary splitting (and its varieties) method. Found by Ramanujan at the beginning of s.XX they were proven by Borwein brothers inthe 80's. There are only a small handful of them having rational terms. They have a 3F2 hypergeometric motive basis with polynomials $P(n)$ of degree 1. Chudnovsky-$\pi$ is one of them. The fastest lemniscate Eq.(7) above also is. Most of times Modular Forms, a specialized area of Number Theory, is required to work on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the last section **B**, the gamma 1/3 cube:

$$\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{7}{12};1;\frac{3^2}{253^2}\right) = \frac{253^{1/6}\,\Gamma^3\big(\tfrac{1}{3}\big)}{2\pi^2\sqrt{6}} $$

where $253 = 11\times23.\,$ [Testing it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=253%5E%281%2F6%29%28gamma%281%2F3%29%29%5E3%2F%282*6%5E.5*pi%5E2%29-2f1%281%2F12%2C7%2F12%2C1%2C%283%2F253%29%5E2%29)  in Wolfram. Source: https://iamned.com/math.

This is derived by applying a cubic and quadratic hypergeometric transformation to the 2f1 elliptic integral series at a singular value.

Comment: No wonder that 2F1 looked familiar. That has got to be related to the one [in my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069657/complete-this-table-of-formulas-for-2f-1-biga-bcu-v-with-algebraic-numb), $$_2F_1\left(\frac1{12},\frac7{12};\frac23;\frac{40^3}{253^2}\right) =253^{1/6}\times\frac23$$ especially since this is also connected to singular values.

Comment: Great!! @CarP24. This $\,_2F_1$ is Eq.(8) bisected (Also noted by J. Guillera in a pers. comm.). It is also Euler or Pfaff Transformation of $z=-\frac{9}{64000}$ series that Tito Piezas III asked in a comment above. In fact $\frac{z}{z-1}=\frac{9}{64009}$. I did not know that it was previously published in that Hakimoglu-Brown site. It gives me an idea to look for a new fast $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$ series. I will update this post if I can find it. Thank you